# Datatables how to hide zeroRecords message when infoEmpty message is there

Tags: datatables

I know the datatables have language option which has lengthMenu, zeroRecords, info, infoEmpty, and infoFiltered. The problem I am facing is , I am not able to hide the zeroRecords message when there is no data.

- "infoEmpty" - displayed when there are no records in the table
- "zeroRecords" - displayed when there no records matching the
  filtering

I want to do it with some datatables config or in a cleaner way, not jquery or java script dome manipulation. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was not able to get people response on this question. I have done much research but could not find a way to do it with datatables configurations then I did it in fnDrawCallBack

```
     fnDrawCallback: function () {                                
            if (this.api().rows().count() === 0) {
                $(this.api().context[0].nTableWrapper).find(".dataTables_filter,.dataTables_length,.dataTables_paginate").addClass("hidden");
            } else {
                $(this.api().context[0].nTableWrapper).find(".dataTables_filter,.dataTables_length,.dataTables_paginate").removeClass("hidden");
            }
     }
```

I believe there may be a better way to do it. Please feel free to answer.